# How do I link a button to another page of my website in Flash?

Tags: flash, hyperlink, instance, actionscript-2, flash-cs6

So far I have this code:

```
on (rollOver) {
    tellTarget ("_root.resources_mc") {
        gotoAndPlay(2);
    }
}
on (releaseOutside, rollOut) {
    tellTarget ("_root.resources_mc") {
        gotoAndPlay(16);
    }
}
on (release) {
    tellTarget (_root.box_mc) {
        gotoAndPlay("resources");
    }
}
```

When I click on my resources button it opens up every other page except my resources page. How do I do this?

Comment: Is this ACtionscript 3? It looks more like Actionscript 2. Anyway, try gotoAndStop.

Answer (score 0):

To link a button to another page of your website, you should use [getURL](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000564.html) method:

```
on (release) {
    getURL("http://stackoverflow.com/", "_blank"); 
}
```